# Flash-Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I want to try [Flash-Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) with the python driver, however I have some concerns regarding the available [python](http://flash-selenium.googlecode.com/files/Flash-Selenium_python_client_r37.zip) extension, it seems aged and there is no example on how to use it... Is there anybody who is using it? Any example on how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Example taken from FlashSelenium page:

```
from com.thoughtworks.selenium.FlashSelenium import FlashSelenium
from com.thoughtworks.selenium.selenium import selenium

url = "http://flashselenium.t35.com/colors.html"
browserType = "*firefox"

selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, browserType, url)
selenium.start()
selenium.open(url)

flashApp = FlashSelenium(selenium, "coloredSquare")
flashApp.percent_loaded()
```